# The Funny string code

Tags: c, arrays, string, reverse

The link to the question is :https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/funny-string

Problem Statement

Suppose you have a string S which has length N and is indexed from 0 to N−1. String R is the reverse of the string S. The string S is funny if the condition |Si−S(i−1)|=|Ri−R(i−1)| is true for every i from 1 to N−1.

(Note: Given a string str, stri denotes the ascii value of the ith character (0-indexed) of str. |x| denotes the absolute value of an integer x)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
char r[10000],s[10000];
int t[10],i,j,n,c1,c2,l,f;
scanf("%d",&n);
for(i=0;i<=(n-1);i++)
{
    t[i]=0;
    c1=c2=0;f=0,l=0;
    gets(s);
    l=strlen(s);
    for(j=0;j<l;j++)
        r[j]=s[l-1-j];
    for(j=1;j<l;j++)
    {
        c1=abs((int)(s[j])-(int)(s[j-1]));
        c2=abs((int)(r[j])-(int)(r[j-1]));
        if(c1==c2)
            f=1;
        else
            f=0;
    }
    t[i]=f;
}
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    if(t[i]==0)
        printf("Not Funny\n");
    else
        printf("Funny\n");
}
return 0;
}
```

This is my code
and the required input/output are

**input**

> 2 
> acxz 
> bcxz

**output**

> Funny 
> Not Funny

But I am getting a different output can anyone help me in what is wrong with the code and the worst output is for test case value 1.I am not getting it how it is giving that value

Comment: Learn how to use a debugger, because then you can step through the code line by line to see what it *really* does, while also being able to see the values of variables, and also evaluate expressions and see their results.

Comment: 'int t[10],i,j,n,c1,c2,l,f;' ....fail:(

Comment: Warning: Don't use `gets()`, use `fgets()` instead.

Comment: Also, don't declare an array of 10000 bytes on the stack.

Comment: *But I am getting a different output...* What output are you getting? And do you really need to support strings that are 10,000 bytes long?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are very close.

The problem is that after entering number using `scanf` buffer is left with one `\n` character which gets interpreted as a end of a string, so the first input is empty string (and no, it's not funny). Before entering the strings, you need to clean the buffer:

```
scanf("%d",&n);
```

should be:

```
scanf("%d",&n);
while (getchar() != '\n');
```

And now it works:

```
2
acxz
bcxz
Funny
Not Funny
```

Of course, after figuring this one out, hear all the advices people posted as a comment to your question. And enable warnings in your compiler.

Answer (score 1):

1) You do not need to store all your outputs in a array and print them later, you can print them simultaneously, otherwise it may exceed memory limit, and implementing it will also waste your time

2)The reason its not working properly is because scanf leaves `\n` in your buffer. You can clear it by adding this after scanf

```
char clean;
while (clean=getchar()!='\n' && clean !=EOF);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /*
         * Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT.
         * Your class should be named Solution.
         */
        String s;
        int t;

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        t = in.nextInt();

        for (int f = 0; f < t; ++f) {
            s = in.next();
            getResult(s);
        }
        in.close(); 
    }

    public static int getAbsoluteValue(int a, int b) {
        int value = Math.abs(a - b);
        return value;
    }

    public static void getResult(String s) {
        char[] cArr;
        String sReverse = "";
        char[] cArrReverse;
        int count = 0;
        cArr = s.toCharArray();

        for (int i = cArr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            sReverse += cArr[i];
        }
        cArrReverse = sReverse.toCharArray();

        for (int i = 0; i < cArr.length - 1; i++) {
            int h = getAbsoluteValue(cArr[i + 1], cArr[i]);
            int k = getAbsoluteValue(cArrReverse[i + 1], cArrReverse[i]);

            if (h == k) {
                count++;

            }
        }
        if (count == cArr.length - 1) {
            System.out.println("funny");
        } else {
            System.out.println("not funny");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you add some explanation how this code answers the question?

Comment: Hi Slfan, Its pretty simple we are reading the string into String variable s and then converting it into character Array cArr for the calculation.
In the mean time I am reversing the string into a different string sReverse and then into a character array cArrReverse.
Then using the Math.abs function getting the absolute value of the difference to determine the String is Funny or not.

Answer (score 0):

```
int main() {

    char s[10000], r[10000];
    int times;
    scanf("%d", &times);
    for (int t = 0; t < times; t++) {
        scanf("%s", s);
        int len = strlen(s);
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            r[i] = s[strlen(s) - i - 1];
        }
        int funny = 1;
        for (int i = 1; i < len; i++) {
            if (abs(r[i] - r[i-1]) != abs(s[i] - s[i-1])) {
                printf("Not Funny\n");
                funny = 0;
                break;
            }     
        }
        if (funny) {
            printf("Funny\n");
        }

    }

    return 0;
}
```